# componentDidUpdate not firing after the first time the component is mounted (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, components, react-props

I have a function that switches windows (components) on a single page by clicking a button.

**The function that swaps windows:**

```
getProfileContent = () => {
    var html = [];
    if (this.state.content === "picks") {
        html.push(<Picks picks={this.state.picks} deletePick={this.deletePick} />);
    }

    if (this.state.content === "api") {
        html.push(<Admin admin="admin" />);
    }

    if (this.state.content === 'settings') {
        html.push(<Settings />);
    }

    return html;
};
```

The content defaults to "picks" when the parent component initially loads and the first time the "Picks" component loads everything works fine because the componentDidUpdate update function below is triggered:

**"Picks" component update function:**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('here')
    if (Object.keys(prevProps.picks).length !== Object.keys(this.props.picks).length) {
        this.sortPicks();
    }
}
```

However, after swapping windows via *getProfileContent* and coming back to the ***"Picks"*** component the *componentDidUpdate* function is not triggered.  I have also tried adding a different "key" value to the Picks component in hopes the new prop would trigger the *componentDidUpdate*, but no luck.  I have the console log outside if the condition so I know componentDidUpdate isn't being called regardless of the condition. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are only checking the size of the array and not the content. Considering `console.log`ing what `prevProps.picks` and `this.props.picks` actually. Is. It might just be new content (which should be rerendered) of the same array size

Comment: The componentDidUpdate function isn't called at all so it's not the condition,  I did console log and everything checks out, thanks for the advice though

Comment: Yep, no problem. Even though my comment was not a resolution to your current problem, it is still a fundamental error that will come back to haunt you if you don't fix it now. In an overwhelming majority of cases, comparing array sizes is not a robust solution.

Comment: That's a good point, I have changed the condition, and voted up.  I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been solved with help from @lanxion.  Basically, the first time the component mounts the componentDidUpdate function is called, but only because of the parent component updating and passing in new props.  The second time the component is mounted the parent already has the correct props, thus only componentDidMount is called and not componentDidUpdate.  Placing the code in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate (with conditionals) solved my issue,

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the props values are not changing, thus the same props values are being passed down and thus have the same length. Quite possibly it IS reaching the `componentDidUpdate()` hook, but the condition returns false and thus you don't go into the `sortPicks()` function. Hard to say without knowing the rest of the code.

Comment: I have attempted a console log outside of the condition in componentDidUpdate() which is not triggered.  So I don't think it's the logic

Comment: hmm. componentDidUpdate is not usually called for first render. So I'm curious as to why it is being called during the initial load.

Comment: You're right it isn't called on initial load but once the parent loads the picks the component is re-rendered and it is called, but I think you just solved my problem, once the parent component switches back the picks are already loaded so it doesn't call componentDidUpdate, but it does call componentDidMount.